# Updating textview based on the position of gridview android

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone tell me that how to update a textview depending on the position of gridview.
I have a gridview which shows some values against the date of every month and the textview at top is the name of the month , now i want that when i scroll to the bottom of lets say January and start scrolling in Feb , the textview  at top get updated to February from January?
I at the moment have the values against each date in an array list (if this information is of any help) 
Any ideas or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Little tricky, but can be done.

1. Create custom Adapter and pass the View of TextView as parameter
2. In getView function you get the position of recently rendered view and here you can change the TextView.

Hope this will help you.